# Checkbox which changes clock's format

Tags: javascript, checkbox, time

I want to create text clock which format can be changed from 24 to 12 hours with PM/AM by checking or unchecking a checkbox. Can you help me create this code?

Here is what I have now:

```js
function GetClock() {
  var d = new Date();
  var nhour = d.getHours(),
    nmin = d.getMinutes();
  if (nmin <= 9) nmin = "0" + nmin

  document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML = "" + nhour + ":" + nmin + "";
}

window.onload = function() {
  GetClock();
  setInterval(GetClock, 1000);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:700');

#clockbox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 38%;
  left: 38%;
  font-size: 10vw;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockbox"></div>
```

Comment: And what is actual problem/question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var clockFormat = 24;
function GetClock(){
var d=new Date();
var nhour=d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes();
if(nmin<=9) nmin="0"+nmin

if (clockFormat == 12 && nhour > 12){
  nhour -=12;
  nmin+= " PM";
}else {
  if (clockFormat == 12 ){
      nmin+= " AM";
    }
  
  }
  
document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=""+nhour+":"+nmin+"";
}

window.onload=function(){
GetClock();
setInterval(GetClock,1000);
}

function setFormat(format){
clockFormat = format;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:700');
#clockbox{
     display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    color:#fff;
    position:fixed;
    top:38%;
    left:38%;
    font-size: 10vw;
    font-family:'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;

}
body{
  color:#fff;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockbox"></div>
  <input type="radio" name="format" value="24" onChange="setFormat(this.value)"  checked="checked"> Format 24<br>
  <input type="radio" name="format" value="12" onChange="setFormat(this.value)">Format 12<br>
```

Comment: Is it there a way to put behind the 12 hours AM or PM?

Comment: sure , it's quite easy